# Sequential separability on $C_p(X)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, gn.general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Definition. Let $E$ be a topological space. Suppose that $E$ contains a sequence $\{x_n\}$  such that for every $x\in E$, there exists  a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ of $\{x_n\}$ with $x=\lim x_{n_k}$. Then we say $E$   enjoys sequential separability.

For a given topological space $X$, let   $C_p(X)$  be  the space of continuous functions on $X$ endowed with the point-wise topology.
It is proved that  $C_p(X)$ is separable iff $X$ is separably submetrizable ([see this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1978-071-01/S0002-9939-1978-0482639-9/S0002-9939-1978-0482639-9.pdf)).

> Question.
> $$C_p(X) ~\textrm{is sequentially separable} \Leftrightarrow X=? $$

Answer (score 0):

N. V. Velichko, “On sequential separability,” Mat. Zametki 78 (5), 652–657 (2005) [Math. Notes 78 (5), 610–614 (2005)].

Comment: A. V. Osipov, “The Separability and Sequential Separability of the Space C(X)”, Math. Notes, 104:1 (2018), 86–95